# ASP.NET Creating Dynamic Order Reference based on database id

Tags: vb.net

Hey I am looking to create an order reference which is something like this

PLC0000001

Where the 1 would be my order id

but lets say it gets to 100 would like

PLC0000100

In VB.NET how could I build up a string like where i know i.e.

the starting part = PLC
Ending part = Order ID

middle = fill in 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to build the order code in SQL? You could do something like this instead:

```
DECLARE @Sequence INT
SET @Sequence = 100

SELECT ('PLC' + REPLICATE('0', (7 - LEN((@Sequence)))) +  CAST(@Sequence AS VARCHAR(5))
```

You can change the number 7 to reflect however many leading zeros you want.

In VB.NET you could do something like this:

```
Dim Number As Integer = 100
Dim LeadingZeros As Integer = 7 - Number.Length

Dim OrderCode As String = "PLC" & Number.ToString.PadLeft(LeadingZeros, "0")
```

Comment: only problem with that is I wont know the order id untill after I insert into database unless I can check maybe the max id of table and +1 it ?

Comment: If you're doing it in SQL, @Sequence would be your MAX orderID. Just increment the MAX orderID by one if needed.

Comment: How can I set @Sequence to max order id tho

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking for VB.NET but I hope you can easily translate this C#:

`int id = 100;
 string s = "PLC" + id.ToString("0000000");`

For the VB it's almost exactly same:

```
Dim id as Integer = 100
Dim s as String = "PLC" + id.ToString("0000000")
```